# Running two activities on the same screen

Tags: android, android-activity, screen

I'm designing a app that can be used to monitor the media and ringer volume for which I'm using  a seekbar for each. How can I make both of them work on the same screen and switch between them. At any given point of time only the initial activity is working, the second one is remaining unresponsive. Thanks and regards.

Comment: There is no need whatsoever for these to be separate activities.

Comment: @CommonsWare then what should I do? Please help me out. Should I use group activity? Regards Dinesh.

Comment: I will be more specific I mean the "seekbar  widget" when I refer to activity UI element.

Comment: "then what should I do?" -- put both `SeekBar` widgets in one activity.

Comment: Okay that sounds good, but I have a doubt @CommmonsWare at any point of time how will the system recognize that the current seekbar in use? Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a two-part activity, where every part is running in its thread and updating the UI via handlers, or you can take a look at [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html), but they're only available since Android 3.0.

Comment: I'm designing the app for android 2.1 any suggestions?

Comment: Then you should look at the first part of my answer.

Comment: can u suggest me the methods to use?

Comment: @Egor: Fragments are possible going back to Android 1.6 via the Android Compatibility Library.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fragments API available as a [library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html) and you can use it in android 1.6+
2. You can use ActivityGroup and place the content of subactivity in corresponding place